# How can I fix the (-215:Assertion failed) error, every time I try running this code for face recognition?

Tags: python-3.x, face-recognition

I am trying to develop a Face Recognition authentication system as part of my university project, and I having a difficult trying to successfully implementing it.

First I found a Python code which function is to take a picture of the user and store in the Database as a first step of the whole process. I keep getting the same error every time I try running this piece of code:

```
import cv2
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    return_value,image = camera.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('image',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1)& 0xFF == ord('s'):
        cv2.imwrite('test.jpg',image)
        break
camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Comment: Would anyone help me out please? I've been trying to find a solution all day and I couldn't find any helpful solution.

Comment: I think your camera capture is not initialized and `image` is not loaded properly. check [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#capture-video-from-camera) please

Comment: I tried it. I got the same error: error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Answer (score 1):

firstly,you need to check whether your camera is working correctly or not!
if you are using inbuilt camera of laptop:

```
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

if you are using external webcam then,

```
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
```

sometime **index** may be veried accordingly with system's assignment, so you can use index vice versa if above mention code didn't work.let me know if it work!!